# Replace website url in wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Im transfering a wordpress site from one domain to another. got the db integrated and the files in through FTP.

How do I replace all of the DB entries from http://url1.com to http://url2.com?

I tried this through SQL but it didnt work.

```
SELECT REPLACE('www.url1.com', 'url1', 'url2');
```

Comment: I work for a development agency and we ended up writing a script that would go through table-by-table and replace occurrences of our dev-url. Since WordPress (for whatever reason) loves to have non-relative URLs all over the place, it was worth it for us. Is this a one-off thing, or do you intend to do it over and over?

Comment: you want an UPDATE query not a select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Better Search Replace** Plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

It is very simple. Before it replaces anything in the database, it will show the number rows that will be affected by running a **Dry Run**.

I recently used it and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

sqldump to a text file, find/replace, re-import the sqldump.

**or**

run queries to update in each table where you need to replace

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the first search results for "mysql find replace":

```
update [table_name]
set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

If you're moving from a development or staging server to a production server, I'd suggest making the links relative rather than changing them to a different absolute URL.